# Alert Same Value for a Li Group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math

I Have a list like

```
<ul>
<li>hello</li>
<li>hai</li>
<li>hai</li>
<li>hello</li>
<li>hai</li>
<li>hello</li>
<li>hai</li>
<li>hello</li>
<li>hai</li>
<li>hello</li>
<li>hai</li>
 ....
</ul>
```

I have to group these li by 4 in jquery.

if user click any li between 1 to 4. i need alert 0; if user click any li between 5 to 8. i need alert 4; if user click any li between 9 to 12. i need alert 8; and go on

Please Help me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: i tried some mathematical equations, but didn't worked

Comment: You could do a massive set of if/else checks...

Comment: but the li is not static. its dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('li').click(function() {
    console.log( Math.floor($(this).index() / 4)*4);
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5mjPq/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've obtained the index of the clicked *li*,

```
((index - 1) / 4) * 4
```

*should give the value you want.  e.g. `((6-1)/4)*4=4`*

Answer (score 0):

Its definitely all about the math.. This is what I came up with.
http://jsfiddle.net/dm9yZ/